# Converting a Cuda-Convnet checkpoint to a Caffe model binary protobuf

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, converters, caffe

I have an old checkpoint (model specification) from a Cuda Convnet model trained by someone else a couple years ago where the training data is no longer available.  I would like to find a way to convert this exact model to a Caffe model file.  Is there a tool (which is currently available and supported) which does this?  I would still interested even if the conversion is only to another ML framework which can export Caffe models (i.e. using Theano, Torch7, etc.) as a bridge.